# what does null function pointer in C mean?

Tags: c, function, pointers

Say we have a function pointer:

```
void (*func0)(void);
```

which is also defined:

```
void func0(void) { printf( "0\n" ); }
```

But say, at some point we try to access the function pointer somehow, then if the MS VS debugger shows that func0 actually points to 0x0000 when I step into the code, what does it mean? And also, please also let me know what is the best fix? Thanks.

Comment: The first line defines a function pointer, with no initialisation, The second line defines a function which happens to have the same name.

Answer (score 8):

It is undefined behaviour to de-reference a null pointer. The fix is simply to ensure that the pointer refers to an appropriate function.

In your case you want something like this:

```
void MyFunction(void)
{
    printf( "0\n" ); 
}
```

and then later you can assign to `func0`:

```
func0 = &MyFunction;
```

Note that I am using a different name for the function pointer variable and the actual function.

And now you can call the function, via the function pointer:

```
func0();
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you are mixing up *naming* and *defining* function pointers. I'll just point out that if you write

```
void func0(void) { printf( "0\n" ); }
void (*func0)(void);
```

you actually have two completely unrelated objects with the same name `func0`. The first `func0` is a *function*, the second `func0` is a *variable* with type pointer-to-function.

Assuming you declared your *variable* `func0` globally (outside of any function), it will be automatically zero initialized, so the compiler will read your line

```
void (*func0)(void);
```

as

```
void (*func0)(void) = NULL;
```

So the variable `func0` will be initialized with the value `NULL`, and on most systems `NULL` will actually be `0`.

Your debugger is now telling you that your *variable* `func0` has the value `0x0000`, which is `0`. So this is really no big surprise.

To your question regarding a "fix" - well, I assume you want a function pointer, pointing to your function `func0`, so you can do the following:

```
void func0(void) { printf( "0\n" ); }
void (*pFunc)(void) = func0;
```

or even better (although on most compilers not necessary) you can write

```
void (*pFunc)(void) = &func0;
```

so you initialize your variable `pFunc` (I highly recommend renaming it!) to point to `func0`. A bit more precise: You take the adress `&...` of the function `func0` and assign this value to your variable `pFunc`.

Now you can "call" the function pointer (which means to call the function which the function pointer points to) by:

```
pFunc(); //will call function func0
```