# error with function pointers usage in C

Tags: function, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void func1 (void) { printf( "1\n" ); }
void func0 (void) { printf( "0\n" ); }

typedef struct {
  void (*func0)(void);
  void (*func1)(void);
}mainJT;

static const mainJT coreJT = {
  core_func0,
  core_func1
};

mainJT currJT;

int main()
{
    currJT=coreJT;
    coreJT.core_func0();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me fix the errors, I am sure I am making some obvious mistakes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't quite clear but I see what I can find.

```
typedef struct {
  void (*func0)(void);
  void (*func1)(void);
} mainJT;
```

Here you are declaring a struct with function pointer members `func0` and `func1`. Then you are trying to define a `coreJT` variable via an initializer list:

```
static const mainJT coreJT = {
  core_func0,
  core_func1
};
```

But this doesn't work, because there are no functions called `core_func0` or `core_func1`!
Also you try to call

> coreJT.core_func0();

which is also incorrect since your struct doesn't have a member of name `core_func0`.

---

For a possible solution try renaming your functions like so:

```
void core_func1 (void) { printf( "1\n" ); }
void core_func0 (void) { printf( "0\n" ); }
```

and call your function pointer by

> coreJT.func0();

Comment: Please let me know how should I rename the functions. It helps if you can post the whole code. Thanks.

Comment: @user1128265 I just looked at another question from you which may be the base problem, so read my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014284/what-does-null-function-pointer-in-c-mean/10056987#10056987) to that first

Answer (score 0):

i see lot of errors:
for eg: the correct way of initializing a structure is :
/* Define a type point to be a struct with integer members x, y */

```
typedef struct {
   int    x;
   int    y;
} point;

/* Define a variable p of type point, and initialize all its members inline! */
point p = {1,2};
```

so your part of the code is :

```
mainJT coreJT = {
  core_func0;
  core_func1;
};
```

completely wrong.

also where are the functions core_func1 core_func0 are declared and defined .i cannot see them.

i guess you first need to go through [structures in c](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29)