# Segmentation fault when creating VertexArray

Tags: c++, opengl, vao

I get segmentation fault when I call `glGenVertexArrays()`. I tryed to set `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE` but I still get the error. Here is my small code.

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

#include <iostream>

int main(int argv, char **argc)
{    

   glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
   glewInit();

   GLuint vao = 0;
   glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
   glBindVertexArray(vao);

   std::cout << "WHY?" << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try creating a gl-context and setting it as current before using glew or any gl-command.

Answer (score 3):

You never verify that `glewInit()` returns `GLEW_OK` (and it won't because you don't have a current GL context) so `glGenVertexArrays()` and `glBindVertexArray()` are both still NULL function pointers.

[Calling NULL is bad.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089896/null-function-pointers)

You should also check that the current GL context supports [VAOs](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) before using them, either via a GL version check (`if(GLEW_VERSION_3_0)...`) or extension (`if(GLEW_ARB_vertex_array_object)...`).

As far as creating a GL context and making it current goes I'd recommend [SDL2](https://libsdl.org/) or [GLFW3](http://www.glfw.org/).

Comment: Oh yes..the GL Context...I feel a bit stupid right now.