# How to make a default argument to parameter which takes function address?

Tags: c++, function, parameters, function-pointers, default-parameters

How would I make a function that takes address of another function as a parameter so that passing it is not necessary.

My first solution was this:

```cpp
void empty_func() {}

void func(void (*additional_func) () = &empty_func)
{
    additional_func();
    // some other code...
}
```

This solution works.

However, I was wondering is there some more convenient way to make passing `additional_function` optional, so I do not have to make a new function (`empty_func()`) and passing it as a default argument?

Comment: `nullptr` (this space intentionally left blank)

Comment: Non-capturing lambda: `void func(void (*additional_func)() = []{})` ?

Comment: For function parameters prefer `std::function<void ()>` and a nop lambda (`[]{}`) as default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As function pointers are also a pointer and null-equivalent for pointer types are `nullptr` so you can assign the value to this default parameter as `nullptr`.

Also, don't miss forget to add `nullptr` check before using it.

```
void func(void (*additional_func) () = nullptr )
{
    if(additional_func)
    {
        additional_func();
    }

    //some other code...
}
```

Also, it is more convenient to define an alias for this function-pointer as use like following:

```
using TPFunc = void (*) ();

void func( TPFunc additional_func = nullptr )
{
    if(additional_func)
    {
        additional_func();
    }

    //some other code...
}
```

***But it is best to use features from `functional` header file*** instead of these raw-function-pointers. Following is an example to achieve this using `functional` header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
 

using TPFunc = std::function<void()>;

void func( TPFunc additional_func = nullptr )
{
    if(additional_func)
    {
        additional_func();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<< "Function pointer is `nullptr`\n";
    }

    //some other code...
}


void fun1()
{
    std::cout << "In 'void fun1()'\n";
}


void fun2()
{
    std::cout << "In 'void fun2()'\n";
}

int main()
{
    func();
    func(fun1);
    func(fun2);
    std::cout<< "Done";
    return 0;
}
```

***Output:***

```
Function pointer is `nullptr`
In 'void fun1()'
In 'void fun2()'
Done
```

Comment: Why is it "the best to use" `std::function` instead of a pointer to function?

Comment: @Kesto2, template `std::function` is just a polymorphic function wrapper. If you wants to play around raw-pointers then it is fine to use raw-function-pointers. Anyways, `std::function` don't provide a performance improvement but I'd say it is best practice to use `std::function`. One benefit which I can think of using `std::function` is that: Function call on  `nullptr` instance of `std::function` will thrown `std::bad_function_call` exception. So, if you wish, you can catch the exception in your code and stop application from terminating.

Comment: That's okay but I think I will stick to the raw-function-pointer for now. Considering that I just want to keep things simple. Anyways thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 6):

> I was wondering is there some more convinient way to make passing additional_function optional so I don't have to make a new function (`empty_func()`) and passing it as a default argument?

You can do it by providing the default argument using curly braces:

```
// alias type for function pointer type
using FunPtr = void (*) (); 

void func(FunPtr additional_func = {})
//                                 ^^^
{
    if (additional_func)
       additional_func();    
       // some other code...
}
```

However, that leads to a [`nullptr` check prior to the function pointer call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089896/null-function-pointers), which makes the above not a convenient solution.

Luckily, there is an alternative. The non-capturing lambdas can be assigned to a normal function pointer type, by which we ensure there is something default to call, and thereby no null check.

```
using FunPtr = void (*) ();
void func(FunPtr additional_func = []{})
//                               ^^^^^^
{
    additional_func();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use optional of function: `std::optional<std::function<void()>> opFunc`